# How to pass data to ionic custom child component from page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to pass a variable from a page to my custom child component and log as 'undefined'. I want this value in child component so that I can call another service onloading child component.
please help.

```
child.component.ts

    import { Component, Input , OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'well-subsurface',
  templateUrl: 'well-subsurface.html'
})
export class WellSubsurfaceComponent {

  @Input() data;
  wID: string;

  constructor(
    public navParams: NavParams) {


  }

  async ngOnInit() {

    this.wID = this.data;
    console.log("------ "+ this.wID)

  }
```

### }

parent.component.ts

```
 import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-asset',
  templateUrl: 'asset.html',
})
export class AssetPage {
 public wID: any;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController
  ) {
  }

  MenuContorl(assetID) {
  this.wID = wID;
  }
}
```

---

parent.html

```
<well-subsurface></well-subsurface>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that you properly input the data like `<well-subsurface [data]="wID"></well-subsurface>`, then you should not use `ngOnInit` but use `ngAfterContentInit`.

As [this angular lifecycle-hooks documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) says, `ngOnInit` does not guarantee that input data is ready via `@Input`, whereas`ngAfterContentInit` does.